# RPM Forumla without division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Real-world application: RPM measurement on Arduino device, which has horrible division performance as it's done in software not hardware. So skip division.

I count crank revolutions using interrupts on a hall sensor. So, $6000$ rpm is $10$ ms, 600 rpm is $100$ ms.

Is there a simple formula that can produce numbers of increasing size given an input value of decreasing size?

thanks!

Comment: If you have much memory you could calculate a table as a one time thing maybe at boot up and store values in it and interpolate in between.

Comment: How often do you need RPM measurements? You could just count how many interrupts you get in a minute (or how many in a second, times sixty). If the data is noisy, this may give better results. You also might see if you can use a unit of *period* rather than *frequency* for your application if you don't want to divide. Also, even if division is slow, it still operates on the order of $10^{-5}$ seconds, which may be insignificant compared to other costs. Really, what you ought to do depends on why you're measuring RPM in the first place.

Comment: Just count how many revolutions you have per second. In your case, multiplying by 60, this is exactly the rpm value. You can change the timebase to avoid multiplying anc can store intermediate values to increase the update frequency.